# how to transfer the result from zrange withscore to array in PHP

Tags: php, redis

```
redis> ZADD myzset 1 "one"
(integer) 1
redis> ZADD myzset 2 "two"
(integer) 1
redis> ZADD myzset 3 "three"
(integer) 1
redis> ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "one"
2) "1"
3) "two"
4) "2"
5) "three"
6) "3"
```

How to transfer this result to key => array in PHP like this:

```
array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use some PHP-Redis extension which make all that things for you.
As example PHPRedis https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#zrange

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: Good luck! Please share your results :)